# Convert data type to xml via generics?

Tags: xml, haskell, serialization, aeson

Is there a library somewhere that can convert data types to xml via generics? Basically like [Data.Aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) but for XML. Or a function that converts a Data.Aeson.Value into xml in some generic way?

If that doesn't exist, how would you convert a custom data type to xml by hand? Most of my googling is showing me how to convert away from XML, rather than to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://github.com/finnsson/Text.XML.Generic is what you're looking for. It's also in hackage, where it's called `text-xml-generic`

Answer (score 0):

I found [tofromxml](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tofromxml), which also solves the problem. It's a little newer and has a few more downloads than [text-xml-generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-xml-generic), but otherwise they look like they both work.